# Modulus of grad

Tags: webmathematica

```
f:= x^2 y^5 + y^3z^4;
grad[x_, y_, z_] = Grad[f, {x, y, z}]; 
mat = {{ 2,1,0},{ 2, 1, 1 },{ 0,3,3 },{ 2,3,1 },{ 1, 3,1},{ 4,4,4 }    }; 
grad[##] & @@@ mat //TableForm
```

Is there a way to use `Modulus` 5 with grad in this Mathematica code?

Answer (score 1):

```
Mod[Apply[ grad  , mat, {1}], 5]
```

Comment: thanks very much, but what does {1} means here.?

Comment: @pat A list with length = 1 and its only element is 1. Depth specification for `Apply`.

Comment: @pat {1} is a level specifier. Mod works elementwise so `Mod[Apply[ grad  , mat], 5]` also works!